# Version Node GCP

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting

"The Node.js 16 runtime will be deprecated on Jan 30, 2024. Please update the function using the latest available version of the runtime."

It's just another question, I want to know if the discontinuation of Node 16, which is scheduled for 30/01, will also affect hosting or just functions?

Thanks

I've already changed the functions, but I don't want to have to do it in the hosting environment as it would take a lot of time at the moment.